# 'How long of a ...'

Tags: phrases

Please settle an argument for me! Is it correct to say 'How long of a sentence [can you make]' as opposed to 'How long a sentence can you make'

Which is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, "How long of a" is not used in a context like the example sentence. Drop the *of,* it's not needed.